# PHP & MySQL Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: php, mysql

Okay when I go to my web page I get the following error below but when I reload the page everything is okay and is displayed fine. What exactly is the problem and how can I fix it?

ERROR.

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host
```

MySQL code.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("example.com", "avd", "password", "avd");
```

Comment: Help us to help you by supplying more info (code, server config etc)

Comment: @andreas I'm not sure what you are asking I'm hosted on godaddy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP & MySQL Error: mysqli_connect() \[function.mysqli-connect\]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335536/php-mysql-error-mysqli-connect-function-mysqli-connect-hy000-2005-unkn)

Answer (score 0):

Server/Port combination is invalid, can't be resolved, or port is bad.

Comment: the server running php, doesn't know how to resolve (turn a domain name to an ip address), the port could also be a string and not an integer value (1-65535).