# PHP & MySQL Error: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting the error below once in a while and then it goes away everything works fine. I was wondering how can I correct this problem? And can someone tell me what in hell is causing this problem?

Error.

```
mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host
```

The error above points to the code below.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("i.db.8473545.hostedresource.com", "i", "password", "i");
```

Comment: then add @ in front of function @mysqli_connect()

Comment: and what will that accomplish?

Comment: It suppresses the error message but won't fix the problem

Comment: @goreSplatter thanks, how can I fix the problem though?

Comment: Could you post some code that directly relates to this error?

Comment: @Jose Vega posted the code the error points too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP & MySQL Warning: mysqli_connect() \[function.mysqli-connect\]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332996/php-mysql-warning-mysqli-connect-function-mysqli-connect-hy000-2005-un)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably on a shared hosting environment with an external MySQL server. The error message hints on DNS problems resolving "i.db.8473545.hostedresource.com".

*As a temporary* fix, find out the IP "i.db.8473545.hostedresource.com" points to and use the IP adress as host name for `mysql_connect()`. See if you still get the error afterwards.